# AttributeError: 'VideoCapture' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I was trying to run a face detection code I copy pasted from https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/detect-faces-opencv-python on PyCharm IDE. I got an error saying:

> "C:\Users\NH\PycharmProjects\Hello_World\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
> "C:/Users/NH/Desktop/WELCOME!/Docs/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/FACEDETECT.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/NH/Desktop/WELCOME!/Docs/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/FACEDETECT.py",
> **> line 5, in 
> _, image = cap.read() AttributeError: 'VideoCapture' object has no attribute 'read'**

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_fontalface_default.xml")
while True:
    _, image = cap.read()
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_gray, 1.3, 5)
    for x, y, width, height in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried the debugger on line 5 but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: Try this: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`. You are missing the device index (typically `0`, but you might need to change that if you have more than one camera connected to your system). The second parameter is the video-capture API preference, which is short for `directshow` via video input, if you are on Windows. More info [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ac4107fb146a762454a8a87715d9b7c96)
.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'VideoCapture' object has no attribute 'read'` should **never** happen. not "even" if the video/device couldn't be opened. the object ALWAYS has that method. -- your installation of python/opencv is broken or you did something we can't see in the code.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the feedback! I have installed both python 3.10 and 3.7 and I made sure I added python to path. For OpenCV I used the "pip install opencv-python" on command prompt. I set the interpreter configuration to python 3.7 . Concerning the code, I just copy pasted it as it was , I did not edit it in any way.